# RuntimeError after installation matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, py2exe, pyqt5

I created app using pyqt5 and numpy. I can create .exe file using py2exe. Ok.

After I made advanced version my app with matplotlib. Ok. I run this app with 'python start.py' successfully. All work well.

I try make .exe now. But I get error 
'`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceed`'.

It is wonder but I can't make .exe with my simple app now (that without matplotlib)
I get repeated strings in terminal (about few thousand strings) for 3-4 seconds.

```
    getattr(parent_module, name.rpartition('.')[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 291, in __getattr__
    self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_h                                                                                                    ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 298, in _find_and_loa                                                                                                    d
    getattr(parent_module, name.rpartition('.')[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 291, in __getattr__
    self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 138, in safe_import_h                                                                                                    ook
    self.import_hook(name, caller, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 298, in _find_and_loa                                                                                                    d
    getattr(parent_module, name.rpartition('.')[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 291, in __getattr__
    self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 135, in safe_import_h                                                                                                    ook
    self._info(name, caller, fromlist, level)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

P.S. if I reinstall python and packages without matplotlib - I can make .exe
Help me please you advise. How avoid it. I need matplotlib in my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

actually , py2exe is a little hard to configure with any package , ( not pure python ) because it has many things unsupported like fonts and encoding that you have to deal with..
and clearly the error in py2exe conversion process rather than your code ( as it works ), but why it still fail after uinstalling matplotlib , i don't know , I cannot guess , because it should not ..

my answer , is recommandation to use pyqt other "plugins" which can replace matplotlib , that is :

- [pyqtDataVisualization](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdatavisualization/intro)
- [pyqtChart](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtchart/intro)

it should be easier to deploy ..

Comment: Thank you. Will try

Comment: I have two app: simple - without matplotlib, and advanced - with matplotlib. I can make exe for simple app before installing matplotlib. But after installing it I can't make exe even for any app (simple or advanced). And the same error at both occasion. I get in termainal for 3-4 seconds printing repeated string (maybe a few thousands string in window) as you can see on code. But I will try after your method. Thank you